# OOTB item Level permission in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server

In my SharePoint Site I have 5 group with all contribute permission and need restrict data so that data not related to particular group not get exposed via any means to other groups. Can any one suggest any solution or item level permission will work out?  Implementing item level permission will cause performance issue in long run of application.

Answer (score 0):

Create five lists/libraries and break the permissions. Remove the groups that should not have any access. Or am I missing something?